# Which test to use for 13 groups?

Tags: group-differences, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

I am conducting a preliminary study on a medical sign.

Without going into details, I have 13 types of dermatological diseases (variable x) presenting as skin lesions. In each group there are between 10 and 150 lesions.

My study consisted of looking at these lesions by dermoscopy, and seeing if a vessel was present. This variable y could be “not present”, “1 vessel”, “2 vessels”, “3 vessels” and “4 vessels”.

I want to know if this sign is more likely to be found in certain types of lesions in my samples.

3 groups have no lesions with any vessels. Less than 2% of all lesions studied have 4 vessels.

What seems more interesting to me is to see the difference between the groups, on the variable “at least 1 vessel”, or “at least 2 vessels”. Indeed, I think that doing analyses on the average number of vessels of each group is less informative (some groups have many lesions with 3 vessels, and others have 90% with two vessels, according to the chi2, there is a difference, but I just want to know if this sign has any interest clinically).

What tests to use? The Kruskal Wallis test will just give an argument to say that the groups are different but not more.

Also, on the visual analysis, many lesions have 1 vessel or more, distributed among 10 groups and this seems little discriminating.

By taking into account 2 vessels or more, 4 groups seem to emerge, and the rest of 9 groups have no lesion with 2 vessels or more, which seems very interesting to me (to say that the presence of 2 vessels or more can allow us to guide our diagnostic approach toward these 4 diagnoses).

But I don’t know what test to use either, without multiplying the tests and increasing the alpha risk.

Thank you for reading me and thank you for your help.